# Array at index 0 is empty

Tags: java

```
String A = "00000000"; //8-bit
String [] Aarr = A.split("");
String [] Aarr1= Aarr.clone();
//trying to do a arithmetic right shift here
Aarr[0]=Aarr1[0];
Aarr[1]=Aarr1[0];
Aarr[2]=Aarr1[1];
Aarr[3]=Aarr1[2];
Aarr[4]=Aarr1[3];
Aarr[5]=Aarr1[4];
Aarr[6]=Aarr1[5];
Aarr[7]=Aarr1[6];
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(Aarr));
```

Why am I getting the output as [,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] instead of [,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] where the first element is empty?

Comment: Dear lord, please name your variables something readable.

Comment: I've run your code and everything looks fine... I got the expected output. The output: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: I can't reproduce your results either. `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

Comment: Sorry, I just fixed the code. Please try now.

Comment: I am getting [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]. Can you check again once

Comment: Could you please check again. I had to fix a few things so that it reflects my exact problem. Now, if you try you should get what I am getting

Comment: You are setting the first two elements to the same value.  You're surprised that they're the same?

Comment: Check the value of `Aarr` right after you split.

Comment: @HotLicks This is normal. It's an arithmetic shift, so the bit on the left has to be the same as previously.

Comment: @Marc-Andre: Right after I split, the value of Aarr is the correct one!

Comment: @HotLicks: That's true and that's what I intend. But my index 0 is empty which it should not be.

Comment: Does this have to be done with arrays? 
String B = A.substring(0,1) + "0" + A.substring(1,7);

Comment: @Klazen108 Your point is well taken, but your implementation is slightly off: `String b = a.substring(0, 1) + a.substring(0, 7);`

Comment: @Klazen108: Unfortunately Yes! The rest of the program is using arrays and it will take me forever to change all the arrays to something else.

Comment: If it were me, I'd probably do the shift using substrings and *then* split that into an array if I needed an array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening because when you `split` a string with the empty string as the delimiter, the first result is *always* the empty string: because every possible string can be written as `"" + "" + "string content"`. Therefore, the first place to "split" this string using the empty string is right there at the beginning.

Your array, right after you split the string, looks like this:

```
["", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]
```

Since you're right-shifting your array and copying the first element (`""`) into both slots `0` and `1`, you end up with two empty strings at the beginning in the final output.

```
["", "", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]
```

---

Note that *the same problem* can occur at the end of strings: because all strings *end* with `"" + ""` as well. However, in the common use of Java's `String.split`, [*trailing* empty strings are discarded](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I have another array that does the same but still produces the right output :(

Comment: Cool! that makes sense, what do you think I should do then?

Comment: @summerNight You have plenty of options. The one that comes immediately to mind is to build your second array like this: `String[] bits = A.split(""); String[] shifted = new String[A.length()];` and then ignore the first index of `bits` when building the new array (use a loop instead of writing out every index). You could also do the shift using String methods (`substring`), and then split that at the end if you need the array (again, cutting off the first result).

Comment: Thanks! I am trying that right now. I will let you know how that goes!

Answer (score 1):

How about a loop:

```
char[] shiftResult = new char[8]; //Or whatever type it has to be
shiftResult[0] = A.charAt(0);
shiftResult[1] = A.charAt(0);
for (int i = 2; i < 8; i++) {
    shiftResult[i] = A.charAt(i-1);
}
```

No empty string splitting required.

Answer (score 0):

there are 9 elements in your array instead of 8.  Is that intentional?  Code should work otherwise.

Comment: I had to fix these: Aarr[0]=Aarr1[0];
Aarr[1]=Aarr1[0];